# Validating 2 forms in the action/view

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I have 2 forms on a page, that I'd like to validate separately.

I have the following:

```
public function executeNew(sfWebRequest $request)
{
    $this->propertyForm = new AdminNewPropertyForm();
    $this->propertyCsvForm = new AdminNewPropertyImportForm();

    $this->processForm($request, $this->propertyForm, $this->propertyCsvForm);

}

protected function processForm(sfWebRequest $request, sfForm $propertyForm, sfForm $propertyCsvForm)
{
 if($request->hasParameter('property'))
 {
     if($request->isMethod('post'))
     {
         $propertyForm->bind($request->getParameter($propertyForm->getName()));
         if($propertyForm->isValid())
         {
             $propertyForm->save();
             $this->getUser()->setFlash('success', 'The property was successfully updated.');
         } else {
             $this->getUser()->setFlash('error', 'The property could not be saved.');
         }
     }
 } 
 else {
     if($request->isMethod('post'))
     {
         $propertyCsvForm->bind($request->getParameter($propertyCsvForm->getName()));
         if($propertyCsvForm->isValid())
         {
             $propertyCsvForm->save();
         }
     }
 }
```

}

I am then displaying both forms in the view.

The problem is, I'm getting an error when passing the forms in `processForm()`

`Strict standards: Declaration of propertyActions::processForm() should be compatible with that of autoPropertyActions::processForm()`

Am I passing the forms correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says you are obviously not doing it correctly ;)

As your `propertyActions` class extends an abstract class `autoPropertyActions` there are some strict standards on implementing the functions declared in the abstract class. That's why it's complaining that you have made some unexpected alterations.

In fact - do you really have to use the `processForm` function? After all you are calling this function yourself, so you can call it whatever you like and the class won't complain then (as the original `processForm` will stay intact).

Comment: I renamed the method to `processNewForm()` and it seemed to work